# Branding Regular GMail for New Address

Tags: gmail, greasemonkey

So, with Gmail adding support for 3rd party SMTP servers, and my lame work email system supporting email forwarding, the logical thing for me to do was to start a gmail box for my work, forward to it from work, and setup my work SMTP (none of that "sent on behalf of" garbage anymore.)

I figured out how to replace the Gmail logo with my company's logo using a Greasemonkey script, and figured out how to replace the "Loading blah@gmail.com" with "Loading my work@email.com)

What I haven't been able to crack, however, is getting the blah@gmail.com address on the top bar to be 'switched' to my new email address (even if only for show). I used a Replace text script, but apparently it doesnt work on JavaScript (when I ran it on the HTML version, it replaced the text, but who wants to replace the HTML version)

LONG STORY SHORT**: Does anyone know of a way I can, using Greasemonkey or something similar, change what email address displays on the top of my gmail window?** (next to 'Offline | Older Version | Help | Report Gmail bug | Sign OUt')

Answer (score 3):

If you own the domain at your work you can register it with google apps http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html and then set your MX servers to google and use their gmail (with your logos) there.

If you don't own the domain, I would NOT recommend forwarding your company email to gmail. I know my company gets very grumpy when my corpoate email leaves their servers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript for your solution:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Gmail Replace Domain
// @author        http://codejoust.com
// @namespace     http://mail.google.com/
// @description   example script to alert "Hello world!" on every page
// @include       http://mail.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
var your_domain = 'yourdomain.com';
var canvas_frame = document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentWindow.document;
var user_id = canvas_frame.getElementById('guser').getElementsByTagName('b')[0];
user_id.innerHTML = user_id.innerHTML.replace('gmail.com',your_domain);
```

As a [gist](http://gist.github.com/212241).